# Determine n related elements with least sum from a matrix?

Tags: matrix, function-construction, conditional

Consider defining a matrix such as `mat`:

```
size = 1000;
rnd = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, size}];
mat = rnd + Transpose[rnd] + DiagonalMatrix[Table[100, {i, 1, size}]];
```

This matrix is symmetric and has off-diagonal entries between `0` and `2`.
I would like to have a function

```
res = getLeast[mat,n];
```

that would return a list of `n` indices between `1` and `size` such that

```
sum = Sum[mat[[ res[[i]] , res[[j]] ]],{i,1,n-1},{j,i+1,n}];
```

gives the smallest possible `sum` out of all possible selections of `n` indices `res`.
Of course one could calculate all possible `res` and sort the corresponding results for `sum` by brute force. But perhaps there is a more convenient way to do this in Mathematica? Thanks for any suggestion!

EDIT:

For example, consider the following 6x6 case:

```
mat = {{101.748, 0.52303, 1.2432, 0.6879, 1.92495, 1.90424}, 
      {0.52303, 100.913, 1.26134, 0.735809, 0.787014, 1.02366}, 
      {1.2432, 1.26134, 101.341, 1.24986, 0.646437, 0.522691}, 
      {0.6879, 0.735809, 1.24986, 101.18, 0.799003, 0.994439}, 
      {1.92495, 0.787014, 0.646437, 0.799003, 100.701, 0.849613}, 
      {1.90424, 1.02366, 0.522691, 0.994439, 0.849613, 101.616}};
```

for `n=3` we can find by brute force that:

```
n = 3;
subs = Subsets[Table[i, {i, 1, size}], {n}];
nums = Table[
        Sum[mat[[subs[[q, i]], subs[[q, j]]]], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}]
       , {q, 1, Length[subs]}];
res = subs[[Position[nums, Min[nums]][[1, 1]]]]
```

> `{1, 2, 4}`

is the correct set of indices, such that `mat[[1,2]]+mat[[1,4]]+mat[[2,4]]` is minimal compared to all other sets of 3 indices.